# Div row all same except first one

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-repeat="characteristic in test.testChar" class="row" >
<div class="col-xs-9 rec">
<div class="rec2" ng-bind-html="translateCharacteristicLabel('test',test.testChar[$index + 1].cell_header) | to_trusted"></div>
</div>           
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.rec{
    font-size: 16px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 50%;
    clear: left;
}
.rec2{
    font-size: 16px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    clear: left;
}
```

With the code above i was able to create the design below:

[image]

As you can see the TYPE text is slightly below compare to the rest. How can I make it all in alignment? (as in all in one line)

Comment: Can you add the actual HTML that gets rendered?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css property `text-align:center; line-heigth: 16px;` on parent container should do the fix

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you just need to add:

```
justify-content: center;
```

to the row. 
If that doesn't work you can try

```
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

in your rec2 elements

It would help if you can make a simple example in jsfiddle/codepen, so others can try out your code easier

**EDIT:**

You also could save lines of code with defining both rec and rec2 at once, like this:

```
.rec, .rec2 {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    clear: left;
}
```

And then add the margin for rec:

```
.rec {
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```